# How to Persist change tracking info of Db Context & Restore?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

> We have to detect changes inside DB Context and schedule the DB update
>   at a later date.

How to persist [change tracker info of Db Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/local-data) into temporary Database, so that these can be restored back into another DbContext instance, at a later date.

> So merely .SaveChanges on newly built Db Context instance should commit the
>   pending changes.

Comment: Did you try something? Why don't you write your ideas (if you have one)? I see ef core in tags but you put a link for ef standard. Please give us more informations.

Comment: Might be via a slightly different route, but did you take a look at Change data capture (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you would need to do, perhaps, is to have a local temporary database that has the same structure as your main (remote) database; then do a SaveChanges into the local database instead of into the main database.

To direct the SaveChanges toward the local database instead of the main one, you would simply need to use a different connection string when creating the DbContext. (Although there has been some discussion of having the ability to change connection on a DbContext, it is not currently implemented, see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8494. ).

So ... say your changes are in a "main" DbContext, you then create a second DbContext for the local database, and just copy the changes over from the 'main' DbContext.ChangeTracker to the 'local' DbContext.ChangeTracker. You can do this by iterating over the ChangeTracker entries and: clone the entity (construct an entity and copy over all the values from EntityEntry.OriginalValues using PropertyInfo.SetValue); attach the entity to the 'local' DbContext; then apply the changes (get the current value using EntityEntry.CurrentValues, test for !EqualityComparer.Default.Equals and if not equal then again use PropertyInfo.SetValue to apply the current value).

It is fairly straightforward if you only need a shallow copy; if you need a deep copy then you will also need to navigate through the relationships that are in the model.

Alternatively to all this, a different approach would be to always save everything to the local database and then have a separate process such as a batch process which copies the values over to the main database. As a general comment, no matter how you do this you will need to deal with any concurrency conflicts that may arise when the local values are sent to the main database.

Steve

P.S. It might also be worth experimenting with the DbContext.Database to see if you can redirect the connection -- if you are willing to go outside of the 'supported' API.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Add an approved field to the table and filter output based on the value(using a view to read only approved items), deleting non-approved records.  (appropriate if most requests will be approved and historical data does not need to be kept).
2. Duplicate the existing table(structure only) on the server, this allows the generated EF classes to be reused, called Requests. Upon approval, use a SQL query to add the record to the main table, and delete the row from the Requests table. If the request is denied, you can add it to a denied table giving a reason for denial.

The advantages to these methods:

1. Since the operations all occur within the same database, as opposed to local or different databases, is that atomic transactions are possible and the usage of existing backup/recovery/availability policies.
2. (#2)A history can be created giving accountability information.

Comment: Hi @Strom, I had assumed that the purpose of the request was to deal with the case where the main database was not available. The OP says that a temporary database is desired.

Comment: PS. Good ideas there --

Comment: @sjb-sjb, My purpose was not to undermine your answer, it was just to give a different point of view to the problem at hand.

Comment: Option 1 looks like the best- If this is just to facilitate an approval work flow, having a whole other database to hold pending changes seems like overkill.

Comment: I agree if it is a workflow problem, but it doesn't look like it to me. If you read the original post he's talking about scheduling it at a later time. I have the impression that this is due to availability or some reason like that. Maybe @Abhijeet can enlighten is on this point.